# how to pass arguments into a nested class in python

Tags: python, class, metaclass

I have the following model:

```
def get_my_model(name1, name2):
    class MyModel(Model):
       class Meta: 
             table1 = name1
             table2 = name2
    return MyModel
```

I am trying to write this without the function and want to pass the arguments `name1` and `name2` directly to the Meta class but I'm not sure how. I tried using constructors but it somehow doesn't work.

```
class MyModel(Model):
       def __init__(self, name1, name2):
             self.name1 = name1
             self.name2 = name2

       class Meta: 
             table1 = self.name1
             table2 = self.name2
```

I also tried setting the constructor on the meta class but didn't work either. Anyone an idea?

Comment: There are no metaclasses here... Do you mean the class nested inside your `MyModel` class that is named `Meta`?

Comment: Why did you think the `__init__` in `MyModel` would be at all related to some nested class, `Meta`? I'm assuming this is django related? Outside fo that, nested classes aren't often used in Python. In any case, it isn't exactly clear what behavior you are expecting

Comment: It can be hacked to work with metaclasses too, but it is **not** related to metaclasses; if you want to use metaclasses regardless, I suggest you read [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/11647025) about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- any reachable variable from `MyModel` or any higher scope's variable up from the class named `Meta`, that's *already* defined
- modify [`ModelBase`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9662193aea2ee982bc8e553c62499aca5e606755/django/db/models/base.py#L404)'s metaclass (patch the file or inherit from)

---

It's not a metaclass! It's just a class in other class's scope named `Meta`. What's happening is that Python has separate contexts/scopes once the execution environment starts building:

- [interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options)
- global (the original namespace you're given once you start the interpreter, [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals))

then the nested ones within the global namespace:

- module/file
- class
- function
- perhaps some other(s)

You can't pass a parameter to the `Meta` class because it's just declared in there. It's not called. Parallel to this would be passing a parameter to a class declaration from the module scope:

```py
# module.py
class MyClass:
    value = <how?>
```

Once you find the place where it's called, **then** you can inject the parameters by modifying the caller function.

```py
class Main:
    class Meta:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("Meta", args, kwargs)

    def __init__(self, name):
        Main.Meta(name)

print(Main(123))
```

If I don't explicitly call `Main.Meta()`, the `Meta` class in this example won't be instantiated.

In case of Django, the `Meta` class is pulled via [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) for the model class [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9662193aea2ee982bc8e553c62499aca5e606755/django/db/models/base.py#L102), therefore you need to target [`ModelBase.__new__()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9662193aea2ee982bc8e553c62499aca5e606755/django/db/models/base.py#L72) with [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)/copy-paste to modify the function so it accepts custom arguments, or, pass them as just class variables (how it's mostly done in Django / [DRF](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f0a5b958a134e8cd94e3ef3263e8fa623ac9b82f/rest_framework/serializers.py#L163)).

```py
class Main:
    class Meta:
        class_var = 123
```

Judging from the [implementation of `Model` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9662193aea2ee982bc8e553c62499aca5e606755/django/db/models/base.py#L404) in Django you might be able to swap the `metaclass` value, but I'm not sure about the inheritance as the `__new__()` of a metaclass is executed when you declare the class that uses it:

```py
# the original ModelBase from class Model(metaclass=ModelBase)
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, *_, **__):
        print("Hello")
        return cls

class MyMeta(Meta):
    def __new__(cls, *_, **__):
        print("Hi")
        # implement your stuff here or copy-paste + patch
        return cls

class Model(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

class CustomModel(metaclass=MyMeta):
    pass

class CustomModelWithInheritance(Model, metaclass=MyMeta):
    pass
```

For metaclasses check:

- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/5994041)
- [this essay](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/metaclasses/)
- [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses)
- [its tests](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/test_metaclass.py)

Regarding `self`: The naming itself doesn't matter, nor will work where you use it, because the `self` is just an implicitly passed instance of a class into a method (a function with a reference to a class instance):

```py
class MyClass:
    def func(self_or_other_name):
        print(self_or_other_name)
MyClass().func()
```

The same way behaves a `cls` argument in a `__new__()` method when creating a class within a metaclass i.e. it's a reference to the ***meta***class instance (a class declaration in a namespace), for which the "description" is the metaclass that creates it.

```py
cls = type("MyClass", (), {})  # create an instance of "type"
cls  # <class '__main__.MyClass'>
# "cls" is class and an instance at the same time
```

The only "special" variable you can use to refer to the class scope are [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) + anything defined within the class scope as a variable + anything in a higher scope be it from a nested class, module or others:

**Edit:**

So for the class variable it was a screw up, this is the correct explanation. For your case it'll be either a function or metaclass patching because we're dealing here with finding the beginning of a "chicken & egg" problem. And that we can do by either looking from above - introducing a function scope and setting values prior the defining of the upper class is finished -, or looking from inside of the creation process (metaclass).

We can't use a class variable, because we're still in the process of defining a class. We **also** can't use the `__init__` to reference the class (or `Meta` nested class) to inject a value there, because we're already in a situation where the metaclass' `__new__()` method has already been executed, thus anything you set there may be used in your case, but won't be present while creating the `MyModel` class.

```py
class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, name):
        MyModel.name = name  # MyModel not defined yet
        # but we can use self.__class__ in the post-poned execution
        # once MyModel is defined (case when calling __init__())
    # we haven't even started to define the Meta nested class

    # starting to define Meta nested class
    class Meta:
        # MyModel not defined yet because the code block
        # of MyModel class isn't finished yet
        table = MyModel.name
        # can't reference because it doesn't exist yet,
        # same applies for Meta, the only thing you have now is
        # the __qualname__ string
```

But!

```py
from pprint import pprint

class RealMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, *_, **__):
        # create a new class - "Main" because it uses "metaclass" kwarg
        new_class = super().__new__(cls, *_, **__)
        # once we have the "Main" class, we can reference it the same way
        # like *after* we define it the normal way
        nested_meta = getattr(new_class, "NestedClassNamedMeta")

        # ~= pprint(getattr(Main, "NestedClassNamedMeta"))
        pprint(("in metaclass", nested_meta))
        pprint(("in metaclass", dir(nested_meta)))
        pprint(("in metaclass", vars(nested_meta)))
        return new_class


class CustomMetaClass(RealMetaClass):
    def __new__(cls, *_, **__):
        new_class = super().__new__(cls, *_, **__)
        nested_meta = getattr(new_class, "NestedClassNamedMeta")
        # set a new class variable without affecting previous __new__() call
        new_class.custom_thing = getattr(nested_meta, "custom_thing", None)
        # do my stuff with custom attribute, that's not handled by Django
        return new_class


class Main(metaclass=RealMetaClass):
    pprint("defining Main class")

    def __init__(self, name):
        pprint(("in instance", self.__class__.NestedClassNamedMeta.name))
        # works, because it's called after the Main class block
        # is finished and executed i.e. defined
        self.__class__.NestedClassNamedMeta.new_value = "hello"

    class NestedClassNamedMeta:
        name = "John"
        custom_thing = "custom"


class CustomMain(Main, metaclass=CustomMetaClass):
    class NestedClassNamedMeta:
        name = "John"
        custom_thing = "custom"

instance = Main("Fred")
# custom_thing is ignored, not added to instance.__class__
pprint(("after init", vars(instance.__class__), vars(instance.NestedClassNamedMeta)))

instance = CustomMain("Fred")
# custom_thing is processed, added to instance.__class__
pprint(("after init", vars(instance.__class__), vars(instance.NestedClassNamedMeta)))
```

Comment: woaaaahhhh,thank you so much for the long answer!

Comment: Welcome, hopefully it helps! If you by any chance find a way for `CustomModelWithInheritance(Model, metaclass=MyMeta)` feel free to ping or edit. I has to work somehow, but I'm probably too tired for today and missing some basic silly thing :D Also, `Meta` in Django and DRF from what I've observed, is just a fancy dictionary so you don't need to use custom functions to prepare the model, or in other words, the core-devs just moved the logic to more abstract layer to make it more user-friendly and automatic.

Comment: @Tom please check again after the edit, the class variable won't work. Or at least not in the way you might expect it to work (have values in a `ModelBase` metaclass).

Comment: @Tom also, re the inheritance, as I've thought, silly thing, I forgot adding `(type)` so the class inherited from `object` instead of type, thus the MRO borked.